# Automated Contract Creation

Tags: pdf, adobe, aem, fdf

I'm at a bit of a roadblock on what to do with a project.  Currently our business hosts thousands of contracts that take info from a web form and populate the contract with that info.  To do this we built a wrapper that takes an HTML page with tags (e.g. [name]), replaces the tags with the info from the web form, and outputs a personalized PDF.  This is done so contracts can be used over and over with varying data.  The big issue with this is that contracts have to be converted into HTML format.  We usually receive them in either PDF or word format then, by hand, have to rewrite them in HTML.  There are converters but they rarely get the formatting correct on the first try.  This takes up almost 90% of the time of one employee.  Obviously this is not ideal and we have decided to work on a solution.  We decided the best way to tackle this problem is to keep the format in PDF and try to avoid any conversions. I've looked into a few solutions:

1. You can create forms on PDF documents in Acrobat Pro which can be filled in to generate custom inputs.  Then using an FDF form generated with info supplied by the user, we can put that into the document where the forms are set.  This is significantly faster to prepare than the HTML approach but has a few issues.  All of the issues revolve around forms being more of a stamp than written into the document like text.
   First, if text is too long for a form then it gets cut off.
   Example: [Too much text for form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdn1D.png)
   Also, it would be difficult to include a form in the middle of a paragraph as it would look weird as it isn't auto-sizing (to my knowledge).
   Example: [Awkward fit in form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KELz.png)
2. My other options I've looked into is looking towards Adobe Experience Manager Forms/Live Cycle Editor/Third Party PDF Generators.  These seem like the best approach from a programming perspective as they have the most flexibility.  But overall the main purpose of this project is to cut the amount of work an employee has to do to prepare an initial contract PDF.  This way almost seems to be more time to set up for each individual contract and we introduce multiple everyday.

So I guess my question comes down to is there anyway to tackle this problem effectively?  The first solution is very close to being optimal but has a few important issues.  Are there any ideas on how to get around these issues?  Is there a third party program that could assist me in what I'm trying to do?  I am sure someone has been in the exact same situation I am in right now and figured I may be able to get some ideas from more experienced developers. Thanks for any help and I can clarify more if necessary.

Comment: Please include relevant content in your question, not as links.

Comment: Have you looked at phodocx? https://www.phpdocx.com/features

Comment: @Dragonthoughts I don't have enough score yet to include photos

Answer (score 0):

From what you told, Adobe AEM Forms would be very oversized. I think, you should build something simple by yourself.

If you get many templates in MS Word, then I would write my own little template engine for Word.

1. Prepare a Word file with the contract and the tags/placeholders in it (just edited with MS Office Word).
2. Then there are plenty of options to programmatically read and manipulate Word files. With your own template engine you generate a personalized Word document (replacing the tags),
3. and finally you convert it into PDF.

With this approach also the conversion from PDF into a template should easier.